# ultimate member user meta fields in user edit

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, plugins

Does someone know if it's possible to edit the fields the ultimate member plugin stores as user meta data?

In users list I see a tab containing the info on these fields, but don't see this info in the user edit page, which impeeds the admin to edit such fields.

Thanks